# Retaining form data if server side validation fails in Spring and Freemarker

Tags: java, spring, web, freemarker

I am new to web application development. 
I have requirement where I have to submit a form and do some server side validations, if the validation fails i need to be on the same page with the data that was entered intact. How can I achieve this?

I am using Freemarker and Spring.

Answer (score 0):

you said you were using Spring. Have you tried Spring validations?